# Canonical isomorphism between $T_x X$ and $\left( m_{x}/m_{x}^2 \right)^\ast$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I have had a look around SE and couldn't find this question but I am also not sure If this has a particular name so If it has been answered before then very sorry. Anyway, In my lecture the lecturer wrote.

For an affine variety $X\subset \mathbb{A}^n$, there is a canonical isomorphism

$$T_x X\cong (m_x/m_x^2)^{*}$$

The notations we are using are

- $T_x X$ is the tangent space at a point $x\in X$ which is defined to be the null space of the Jacobian matrix $J(x)=\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_{j}}(x)$ shifted to $x=(b_1,b_2,...,b_n)$. Note that here $\{f_1,...,f_l\}$ is any set of generators for $I(X)$. In another way, it can be said that $T_xX$ is "cut out" by the equations

$$\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_j}(b_1,...,b_n)(x_j-b_j)=0$$

- $m_x=\{f\in k[X]|f(x)=0\}$. Note that here, $k[X]$ represents the affine co-ordinate ring.

The Question: I would like a proof of this please. The lecturer started off with

We constructed an isomorphism $d_x:\frac{m_x}{m_x^2}\rightarrow T^{*}_x X$. This is already really weird, wouldn't we want to construct an isomorphism between $T_xX$ and $(\frac{m_x}{m_x^2})^{*}$). Anyway, continuing
For a polynomial $F\in k[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]$ define

$$d_xF=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_1}(x)t_i$$. Another weird thing, where did these $t_i$'s come from. Anyway because of this everything else I wrote down makes little to no sense.

Note that the star is said to represent the dual. Which raises another question, what is $T^{*}_x X$ mean, why is the star only on the $T$ (this is how she wrote it), is it some kind of adjoint? You may wonder why I didn't ask this at the time but it was in the last 30 minutes of a 2 hour lecture so I really had no idea what was going on at the time and was trying to frantically write down what was going on. Lectures are not recorded, we are not following a textbook and there are no lecture notes so I don't really know where to look. With that said, if there is a book that contains this particular proof then feel free to just direct me to that, but please make sure it uses the same terminology (tangent vector spaces, etc) that I have here. Also I do not know schemes, please stick to varieties. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $T^{*}_x X$ is abuse of language for $(T_x X)^{*}$:  it just saves a couple of brackets.